# MSAccess Query a string matching a pattern

Tags: sql, string, ms-access, pattern-matching, ms-access-2007

I have a table with a string field containing location information. I want to be able to query this table and retrieve all of the tags matching the format xxxxxxAA where xxxxxx is a 6-digit number and AA is two alphabetic characters.

Is there a method of querying this using SQL or is this something that I need to do in VBA?

Sample data:

```
BGS5 PM RGP5
022051PM
022201PM
030539PM
WAS3N
179546MM
```

And I want to return the following without knowing the values:

```
022051PM
022201PM
030539PM
179546MM
```

thanks in advance
Jason

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query with a `Like` comparison in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT y.text_field
FROM YourTable AS y
WHERE y.text_field Like '######[A-Z][A-Z]'
```

The `#` matches a digit.

`[A-Z]` matches one character from a character class consisting of only letters.  That character class is actually upper case letters.  However, the comparison is case-insensitive, so will match lower case letters, too.

Comment: If your source data is a native MS Access table, query criteria are always case-insensitive. ``Option Compare Binary`` only applies to VBA code such as ``If text_field Like "######[A-Z][A-Z]" Then...``.